# Objective C,Can I Include a package?

Tags: objective-c

Let'say I have more than 50 header fiels to include..
I can do this in Java like this (I can use "*")

```
 import micrograph.message.*;
```

Can I do something like this in Objective C?

Comment: What about a header file named `*`? That would make this ultimately suck like hell. :) In Java this is not a problem since `.java` files need to be named exactly as the classname, which cannot have `*`'s in them anyway.

Comment: On second thought, do you really need to import all 50 header files? That seems like an awful lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't do that. What people usually do (assuming all your 50 header files are related) is to create a single header file that has the import statements for each individual header file. You then import that single header file when you need it.